# "З наступаючим Новим роком!" Чи правильно це?

Tags: вживання-слів, росіянізм, дієприкметники

Кожного року, 31 грудня, українці вітають один одного фразою:*"З наступаючим Новим роком!"*. На превелике моє здивування, це неправильно. В [Академічному тлумачному словнику](http://sum.in.ua/s/nastupajuchyj) слово *наступаючий* має абсолютно інше значення. До того ж це схоже на кальку з російського слова *наступающим*. То ж як правильно сказати цю фразу?

Comment: В наведеному Вами академічному «Словнику української мови» слово «наступаючий» якраз має **саме потрібне** значенння. «Наступаючий — дієпр. акт. теп. ч. до наступати 2, 3, 5»; «наступати — 5. Те саме, що наставати 1, 2. Надворі, бач, Наступає свято... (Тарас Шевченко, II, 1963, 184); Тихо в полі, гай темніє, Наступає літній вечір (Леся Українка, IV, 1954, 111); Весна наступала швидко, нестримно, навально (Василь Козаченко, Сальвія, 1959, 199)». Інша справа, що [дієпр. є, але занадто їх використовувати нетипово](//www.facebook.com/groups/367613903441695/permalink/905924202943993/).

Comment: Друзі, ми маємо велику проблему низької активності. Наприклад, це запитання має **10,000 переглядів** і лише один upvote (мій). Прохання активніше брати участь у голосуванні. Подробиці [тут](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17/8).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [тернопільський журналіст закликає українців правильно вітати з Новим роком](https://www.0352.ua/news/1487086)

> "Новий рік в українців — прийдешній,
> «Наступаючий» — у росіян,
> Якщо ти в Україні тутешній, —
> Не пхай суржику до привітань!"

[image]

- Олександр Авраменко пропонує

> З прийдешнім святом! З передсвятом! Або просто - з Новим роком, з Різдвом Христовим!

- [Блог Пономарева: як правильно вітати з Новим роком](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-42515894) (тут цікава думка)

> Узагалі вітати потрібно з якоюсь подією, що є наслідком фізичних чи розумових зусиль людини: з успішним закінченням навчання, з відкриттям у якійсь галузі, з установленням рекорду, з добрим урожаєм і под.
>
> **Що ж до Нового року, який настає незалежно від волі чи зусиль людей, то в українській мові доречні вислови:** *бажаю (зичу) щасливого Нового року, щастя вам у Новому році, хай щастить у Новому році.* Їх і варто використовувати.
>
> А якщо вже комусь дуже хочеться вдатися до кальки з російського *с наступающим Новым годом*, то хай каже *з прийдешнім Новим роком, з настанням Нового року.*

Answer (score 4):

Оскільки активні дієприкметники не властиві українській мові, є два варіанти:

1. перекладати зворотом "З Новим Роком, що настає!"
2. перекладати ситуативно і бажати "Веселих новорічних свят!"

В останньому випадку відбувається повна заміна слів, але збережено їхній сенс і мету висловлювання. Адже коли ми кажемо "З Новим Роком!", то маємо на увазі, що Новий Рік вже настав. Традиційне привітання "с наступающим!" рос. має на меті побажати весело провести свята, що вдало реалізує фраза "Веселих новорічних свят!"

Answer (score 3):

На це питання коротко відповідає сайт [Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/antusurzhuk/shhasluvogo-novogo-roku1)

[image]

Comment: Цікаво, це збігається з думкою пр. Пономарева. Якби ви вчасно знайшли і додали цитату з цього блогу для пояснення чому саме так, то галочка була б ваша;)